# Sass loop incrementing by 100

Tags: css, for-loop, sass

I want to write a for loop which increments with 100 each time (`$i`), and increments another variable by 50 each time (`$j`).

I tried to follow the examples in other questions about sass incremental loops, but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to apply to my case specifically.

```
$max: 2600;
$step: 100;
$j: 150;

@for $i from 1000 through $max {
  $i: $i + $step;
  $j: $j + 50;
  // stuff
  @media screen and (min-height: #{$i}px) {
    .item {
      transform:
              translateY(calc(-100% - #{$j}px));
    }
  }
}
```

this is the *current* CSS output:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 1100px) {
  .item {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 200px)); } }

@media screen and (min-height: 1101px) {
  .item {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 250px)); } }

@media screen and (min-height: 1102px) {
  .item {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 300px)); } }

// ..etc
```

the *desired* CSS output:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 1000px) { // $i is 1000
    .item {
      transform:
              translateY(calc(-100% - 150px)); // $j is 150
    }
  }

@media screen and (min-height: 1100px) { // $i is 1100
    .item {
      transform:
              translateY(calc(-100% - 200px)); // $j is 200
    }
  }
@media screen and (min-height: 1200px) { // $i is 1200
    .item {
      transform:
              translateY(calc(-100% - 250px)); // $j is 250
    }
  }

...

// and so on and so forth until min-height is 2600
```

EDIT

This is the working code, thank you

```
$max: 26;
$step: 100;
$j: 100;

@for $i from 10 through $max {
  $k: $i * $step;
  $j: $j + 50;

  @media screen and (min-height: #{$k}px) {
    .item {
      transform:
              translateY(calc(-100% - #{$j}px));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$max: 26;
$step: 100;
$j: 150;

@for $i from 1 through $max {   
    $k: $i * $step;
    $j: $j + 50;

    // Use $k and $j in the styles instead of $i
```

Instead of adding `$step` to `$i`, you need to multiply `*` it with the `$step`. Also, change the variable name from `$i` to something else since it will override the loop variable `$i`.

Edit: Just realized you will also need to change your start and end of the loop.

**IMPROVED ANSWER:**
My old answer works but, I believe it works at the expense of readability. I would suggest you initialize `$k` with an initial value just like you did with `$j` and add `$step` to `$k` each time **independent of `$i`** in each iteration:

```
$max: 26;
$j: 150;
$k: 100;
$stepK: 100;
$stepJ: 50;

@for $i from 10 through $max {   
    $k: $k + $stepK;
    $j: $j + $stepJ;

// Use $k and $j in the styles instead of $i
```

Comment: > Edit: Just realized you will also need to change your start and end of the loop. --  You're right. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @Aerra Please refer to my improved answer. I believe using multiplication with `$step` for `$k` and addition for `$j` makes it less understandable for future readers. I have improved so, the calculations are readable, consistent and more understandable.